# Display contents of Oracle AQ SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE

Tags: oracle, jms, advanced-queuing

I have an application that uses JMS op top of Oracle advanced queuing. I would like to do a query on the queue table that shows the content of the message (which in my case is XML). So when I do a 'select user_data from [queue_table]' I get 'AQ SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE' as a response.

Is there a function so that the contents of this message can be shown? Something like 'select FUNCTION(user_data) from [queue_table]' or something?

I googled, scanned numerous Oracle articles about queuing, but I cannot find this thing. I suspect there is a simple way to do this, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I struggled with this one as well. I've written an answer here: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/02/whats-in-my-jms-queue.html .

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: "select queue.user_data.text_vc from [queue_table] queue"
I added the answer here, so I can promote the answer as the solution to the problem, and I want the answer to be complete.

Comment: I have found that larger text are stored in queue.user_data.text_lob instead of text_vc

Answer (score 9):

So I suppose it should be:

```
select queue.user_data.text_vc from [queue_table] queue
```

Comment: Exactly. You should use an alias or the table_name itself in front of the user_data.text_vc. Otherwise it starts looking for a package user_data containing a function called text_vc, resulting in the error message ORA-00904: "USER_DATA"."TEXT_VC": invalid identifier

Answer (score 3):

The answers here don't handle the display of larger contents, stored in `user_data.text_lob`.
If the content is larger than a certain amount of bytes (4000?), `text_vc` will be `null` and you have to look at `text_lob` (which would be `null` otherwise)

In order to show all data, regardless it's size, you could use the following query using [`nvl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm):

`SELECT nvl(q.user_data.text_vc, q.user_data.text_lob) FROM [queue_table] q`

I guess you could (and should consider to) use [`coalesce`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) instead of `nvl`, because it [doesn't evaluate the second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950103/1436981), if the first one is already different to `null`, but I haven't tested that one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the comment of stuXnet:

```
SELECT nvl(to_clob(q.user_data.text_vc), q.user_data.text_lob) FROM queue_table q;
```

without to_clob you will get ORA-22835 for data larger than 4000 chars because it preserves the space of the first argument, which is only VARCHAR2.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following command:

select user_data from [queue_table] name