# display column name and number of null values present in that particular column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the number of null values present in each column in a table.
something like this..
I have a table called `customer` and fields in the `customer` are `cust_id,cust_name, cust_add,cust_gender,cust_phone` etc

I want output like this

```
Column name        Number of null values

cust_id                      0
cust_name                    2
cust_add                     5
cust_gender                  3
cust_phone                   5
```

.
.
.

and I am using oracle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841551/how-can-i-count-only-null-values-in-oracle-plsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to display data as columns:

```
select 
    sum(case when cust_id is null then 1 else 0 end) cust_id,
    sum(case when cust_name is null then 1 else 0 end) cust_name, 
    sum(case when cust_add is null then 1 else 0 end) cust_add,
    ..... 
FROM
    customer
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple -

```
SELECT column_name, num_nulls
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'CUSTOMER'; -- Or whatever is your table name.
```

Read more on [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm#I1020277).

Comment: That is only a rough estimate.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, that's true. Using this query, I believe, we only get the statistics from the last time when the table was analysed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is exactly what I was trying.

Comment: But How do you write a query which with dynamic inserting? the above query will only give proper value once the statistics are updated.

Comment: Simple - run `ANALYSE <tablename>` before running this query. Otherwise you will have to use dynamic SQL statements in a PL/SQL procedure, through which you will pass a `REF CURSOR` as an `OUT` parameter. That's a long story. `ANALYSE` will do for you.