# How to deal with (maybe) null values in a PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, null, prepared-statement

The statement is

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = ?
```

and the parameter is inserted via java.sql.PreparedStatement 'stmt'

```
stmt.setString(1, y); // y may be null
```

If `y` is null, the statement returns no rows in every case because `x = null` is always false (should be `x IS NULL`).
One solution would be

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = ? OR (x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)
```

But then i have to set the same parameter twice. Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not use prepared statements. I use SQL strings, and then I replace `= NULL` with `Is Null` in the SQL string. Works like a charm.

Comment: That is not type safe and possibly vulnerable for injection attacks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've always done it the way you show in your question.  Setting the same parameter twice is not such a huge hardship, is it?

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = ? OR (x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your note. So you vote for 'this is best practice'?

Comment: I've never found a better way.

Comment: Having two separate SQL might be preferable if performance is important, though, because the access path will be different depending on whether you want IS NULL or not.

Comment: Another example where simplicity comes closest to elegance

Comment: Sure, not a huge hardship, especially when you have `x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ?` and have to rewrite all of that because of the marvelous idea of SQL to treat NULL like nothing else does.

Answer (score 10):

There is a quite unknown ANSI-SQL operator `IS DISTINCT FROM` that handles NULL values. It can be used like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x NOT IS DISTINCT FROM ?
```

So only one parameter has to be set. Unfortunately, this is not supported by MS SQL Server (2008).

Another solution could be, if there is a value that is and will be never used ('XXX'):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE COALESCE(x, 'XXX') = COALESCE(?, 'XXX')
```

Comment: Tried it with MySQL+PHP PDO and it also returned `false` when trying to prepare the statement :(

Comment: [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) works well with PostgreSQL

Comment: In old versions of Oracle, NVL may be used for the same thing, but COALESCE is nicer if available (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce).

Comment: Looks like is distinct from pretty much only works on postgresql. On mysql you can use the operator x<=>? for not equals and not x<=>? for equals.

Answer (score 6):

would just use 2 different statements:

Statement 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x is NULL
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = ?
```

You can check your variable and build the proper statement depending on the condition. I think this makes the code much clearer and easier to understand.

**EDIT**
By the way, why not use stored procedures? Then you can handle all this NULL logic in the SP and you can simplify things on the front end call.

Comment: Thanks dcp, this looks straight forward to me. But imagine if my statement doesn't have 1 parameter, but 5. I would need 5^2 Statements = 25!

Comment: So this will avoid the problem that it still says ` = ` instead of ` IS `?

Comment: @dcp, you seem to have changed your answer from one thing to something quite different.  Why?

Comment: setNull doesn't do anything that setString(col++,null) doesn't already do.  setNull is more useful for types that don't have a natural null, like int or double.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - Yes, sorry for that. I was thinking he could use setNull, but that won't work for his case. That's only useful when you want to set a null value for something you're inserting/updating.

Comment: @Mulmoth - As mentioned in my edit, one thing you may want to consider is using a stored procedure, then you can handle the logic in the SP.

Comment: @dcp, I don't like stored procedures, because they tend to complicate deployment, maintenance and debugging. However, your suggestion is another aspect.

Comment: @Mulmoth - Interesting. I've found stored procedures to simplify maintenance tremendously, because the SQL code is compiled on the server. Plus, I can re-use the SP code in other applications rather than re-inventing the wheel each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use for instance mysql you could probably do something like:

```
select * from mytable where ifnull(mycolumn,'') = ?;
```

Then yo could do:

```
stmt.setString(1, foo == null ? "" : foo);
```

You would have to check your explain plan to see if it improves your performance. It though would mean that the empty string is equal to null, so it is not granted it would fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Knubo, but i cannot make sure that empty strings are not used as a value.

Comment: If you really really need the performance, you could pick some value that you are sure that never would be present to test for. This would be a performance hack, so I'd rather avoid it if you could. (For instance, it could be that your data never contains a single €, so you could check for that instead of ''.

Comment: You were right on the money with your performance concern. It's VERY slow. I clock in at about 4000 times slower, on average, than queries without `IFNULL`. ~50ms instead of microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g, I do it this way because `x = null` technically evaluates to `UNKNOWN`:

```
WHERE (x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)
    OR NOT LNNVL(x = ?)
```

The expression before the `OR` takes care of equating NULL with NULL, then the expression after takes care of all other possibilities. [`LNNVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions078.htm) changes `UNKNOWN` to `TRUE`, `TRUE` to `FALSE` and `FALSE` to `TRUE`, which is the exact opposite of what we want, hence the `NOT`.

The accepted solution didn't work for me in Oracle in some cases, when it was part of a larger expression, involving a `NOT`.