# Prepared statement with set null in query doesn't return any record

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I use prepared statements to read/write data in my DB (SQLite). In my table `INVENTORY`, there are records which have `null` value in the column `paleta` (the column is defined as `VARCHAR` in the table). I want to select these records and I tried:

```
sq = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE paleta = ? AND product = ? AND lot = ?";
//...
stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
stm.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
stm.setString(2, "theIdOftheProduct");
stm.setString(3, "theLotOftheProduct");

ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

The above query doesn't return anything.. I removed the `paleta = ?` and I get the records I want.. How can I define the query like `SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE paleta is null etc..` using the query parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is equivalent to writing `SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE paleta = NULL ...`, which doesn't work.

Since you are essentially searching for rows having a constant value in the `paleta` column (which happens to be `NULL`), you can eliminate the first query parameter and explicitly check for null:

```
sq = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE paleta IS NULL AND product = ? AND lot = ?";

stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
stm.setString(1, "theIdOftheProduct");
stm.setString(2, "theLotOftheProduct");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eran, I thought also to eliminate the 1st query parameter.. However, I don't understand why my approach isn't working...

Comment: @yaylitzis Well, I'm not sure if that's the reason, but when I run a SQL query such as `SELECT something from someTable where someColumn = NULL;`, I get empty result even if `SELECT something from someTable where someColumn IS NULL;` returns results. Perhaps `setNull` is meant to be used only to update columns to null.

Comment: @yaylitzis Added some mySQL reference.

Comment: You are right, but why quote the MySQL documentation on a question about SQLite?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My bad, I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: I have the same question as how OP phrased it, but this doesn't answer my question. I want a single `PreparedStatement` with which I can select null values or specified values.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215618/1052284

You'll have to decide upon an unused value. I simply kept it at `''` since I don't have empty values.

```
sq = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE IFNULL(paleta, '') = ? AND product = ? AND lot = ?";
//...
stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
stm.setString(1, ""); // '' for NULL, otherwise a specific value
stm.setString(2, "theIdOftheProduct");
stm.setString(3, "theLotOftheProduct");
```

But beware if you many queries, it's VERY slow. I clock in at about 4000 times slower, on average, than queries without `IFNULL`. ~50ms instead of microseconds.