# Last login joining two tables

Tags: sql, join, authentication, primary-key, max

I have two tables:

```
members (
  userid int primary key
)

login_history (
  userid int,
  login datetime
)
```

An entry to login_history table is made every time a user logs in.

I'm trying to write a query to find every users last login time.  ie.  The MAX(login) or return null if the user has no login history.  What's the best SQL to accomplish this?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT m.userid, MAX(l.login) 
   FROM members m LEFT OUTER JOIN login_history l
   ON m.userid = l.userid GROUP BY m.userid
```

Comment: @Yada, as far as I can tell, it's the only one posted so far that will work.

Comment: Thanks.  Need to keep this snippet in the memory bank.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
select nvl((max(login_history.login)),NULL), login_history.userid
from login_history, outer members
where login_history.userid = members.userid
group by login_history.userid
```

Comment: `nvl` → `COALESCE`, no reason not to use the standard function. Actually, with a second arg of null, can't you just omit it entirely?

Comment: @derobert - i thought they were both standard?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: nvl is an Oracle extension. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: @derobert - i think it will skip them and you would have to outer join in that case of eliminating `nvl()` or `coalesce()`

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: Actually, I think you need the outer join anyway, if you want to guarantee getting a row back for each members.userid. So that should probably be `from members m left join login_history lh on (m.userid = lh.userid)` and the select should be `m.userid`.

Comment: @derobert - yeah, i was thinking the same.  except `from login_history, outer members` as the only change

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: I think that `, outer members` syntax might be an Oracle-ism too... And you definitely need to change the select clause as well (because it will be null). Also, I missed it, you need to change the group by to be `m.userid` too.

Comment: @derobert - it is oraclism... haha - leave an answer, vote me down, and curse me off!  just kidding, but im not just going to rip off your ideas into my answers past the `outer` which i had considered on my own anyway

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: No, please go ahead and update your answer. If it feels wrong to be getting credit for my suggestions, just put a thanks at the bottom.

Comment: You need to draw the userid column from the _members_ table, not from login_history, for this to work.

Comment: @larry - yeah thats what derobert was saying too

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure this works.  I'm using SQL Server.  Don't know what NVL function do or what outer is.

Comment: @yada - `nvl()` and similar functions explained here - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp.  `outer` types are explained here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29.  in a nutshell, `nvl()` handles the secondary selection criteria found if first field is of `NULL` value, and `outer` handles how to join tables.  `select field from table, outer another_table` will select values from `another_table` even if corresponding key is not in `table`