# adding conditional statement inside UPDATE

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements

The query:

```
UPDATE empPac
    SET quantityLimit = allocation,
        allocationStart = '"&allocationStart&"',
        nextUpdate = DATEADD(mm, allocationMonths, "&allocationStart&"),
        lastUpdate = GETDATE(),
        quantityIssued = 0,
        quantityShipped = 0
    WHERE allocation IS NOT NULL AND
          allocationMonths <> 0 AND
          (nextUpdate <= DATEADD(mm, "&checkCondition&", GETDATE()) OR
           nextUpdate IS NULL) AND
          empIdent in (select empIdent
                       from employee
                       where custIdent='"&custIdent&"')
```

What I want to do is add a conditional statement to the `SET quantityLimit = allocation` so that rather than having the `WHERE allocation IS NOT NULL`, I want it to have a conditional statement such as `SET quantityLimit = ((allocation IS NULL) ? 0 : allocation)`

Comment: MSSQL. the conditional statement i wrote is PHP shorthand, but i didnt know how else to show an example of what i wanted done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

```
SET quantityLimit = ISNULL(allocation, 0)
```

Equivalent functions for other databases are [`NVL()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) for Oracle and [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for MySQL and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

---

What you really should be using though is `COALESCE()` if you want to increase the portability of your code. `COALESCE` is part of the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and widely supported across RDBMSes.

Comment: And at least in Oracle you'd better use coalesce because nvl is a pl/sql function and coalesce is natively implemented. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: Isn't COALESCE the ANSI standard?

Comment: @ConradFrix It is. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What database do you use?
For example, in oracle sql you can write `case when allocation is null then 0 else allocation end` or `nvl (allocation, 0)` or `coalesce (allocation, 0)`

And [case syntax in MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258235%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is the same as in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the TSQL (MSSQL) way:

```
SET quantityLimit = isnull(allocation,0)
```

Alternatives...

```
SET quantityLimit = CASE WHEN allocation is null THEN 0 ELSE allocation END
--This one might be handy if you wanted to check for more than just null values.  Such as:
----...CASE WHEN allocation is null THEN 0 WHEN some_other_value THEN 1 WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE allocation END

SET quantityLimit = coalesce(allocation,0)
--This one gives you the first non-null value it finds, given a list of places to look.  Such as:
----...coalesce(allocation,some_other_field,some_nuther_field,...,0)
```