# Oracle SQL update query only update values if they are null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following queries where I am updating values only if they are null.

Is it possible to put all of these into a single query?

```
UPDATE test
SET test1 = 'hello'
WHERE test1 IS NULL
```

and

```
UPDATE test
SET test2 = 'world'
WHERE test2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try:

```
UPDATE test
   SET test1 = NVL(test1, 'hello'),
       test2 = NVL(test2, 'world')
 WHERE test2 IS NULL
    OR test1 IS NULL;
```

Though it may fire your update triggers even for the rows that are effectively unchanged.

Comment: The trigger issue will be relevent whether you use COALESCE or NVL. IMHO COALESCE is overkill for a straightforward null test.

Comment: The only reason I would choose COALESCE over NVL is that it is standard while the latter is not. Either way is fine with me. :)

Comment: Could you define "Standard"? I believe NVL has been used by Oracle for quite some time and this is an Oracle question.

Comment: Sorry, ANSI standard. Also NVL evaluates both arguments while COALESCE returns the first non-null, only evaluating up to that point.

Comment: I like the point about NVL evaluating both arguments and COALESCE only to the first non-null. For this question it would be barel noticeable but in the case of a subquery in the NVL or similar then it could be much more efficient.

Comment: Here's another difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: I appreciate those differences and under certain circumstances it would really be worth using COALESCE over NVL, however, in terms of readability and obvious code intent it could be argued that NVL is more descriptive of the purpose of the code. Horses for courses.

Comment: Agreed. And NVL will save keystrokes in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE test
   SET test1 = COALESCE(test1, 'hello')
     , test2 = COALESCE(test2, 'hello')
 WHERE test1 IS NULL OR test2 IS NULL
```

COALESCE() works similarly to NVL() in this circumstance -- returning the first non-null value.

Comment: So will this only update test1 if test1 is null and test2 = "abc"??

Comment: @Tom, it will only update test1 if it is null regardless of what is in (or not in) test2.

Comment: Do I still need the where in this case?... I will of course add a `WHERE user_id = 'myuserid'`

Comment: Technically speaking it will update test1 if it's non-null but it will set it to its current value. That's why triggers can be an issue. They will fire even though you're updating a column to its current value.

Comment: if you don't include the `WHERE` clause to test for nulls, rows where both test1 and test2 are not null will needlessly be updated.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of the case where one has an UPDATE OF test1 trigger; it will fire even when only test2 is null.

Comment: Tried `COALESCE` and it gave me `ORA-12704: character set mismatch`, but had no problems at all when using `NVL` in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test
SET Test1 = COALESCE(test1, 'hello'),
    Test2 = COALESCE(test2, 'world')
WHERE test1 IS NULL OR
      test2 IS NULL
```