# Function that is opposite of nvl

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been scouring the internet trying to find an answer to this but I am coming up empty handed. I was wondering if there is a function that acts as an opposite to the `nvl` function. Something like this:

```
UPDATE transaction_review
   SET "function use if null"(review1,review2) = 'Yellow',
       "function use if null"(reason1,reason2) = 'Audit'
 WHERE ACCOUNT = '11111111'
```

Essentially, the `update` would pick review2 if review1 is already populated. Is there any `function` like this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL update query only update values if they are null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633398/oracle-sql-update-query-only-update-values-if-they-are-null)

Comment: there's a proper answer in the question I linked - use that.

Comment: The NVL2 comes close to what you're looking for.  You'd need to use dynamic SQL, however, to accomplish your goal as Oracle doesn't allow column names to be chosen dynamically.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly try do use **[coalesce](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php)** function as below

```
UPDATE transaction_review
set review1 = coalesce(review1,'Yellow'),
    review2 = coalesce(review2,'Audit')
WHERE ACCOUNT = '11111111'
```

Comment: Yeah I thought `coalesce` just picked the first field that isnt null.

Comment: @user2405778 That is true  :) and I think it solve your problem

Comment: No I needed the first field that IS null, not ISNT null.

Comment: @user2405778 if `review1` is null then the update set `Yellow`, if not nothing will happen

Answer (score 3):

Try NVL2 command in plSQL.

> The NVL2 function accepts three parameters. If the first parameter
>   value is not null it returns the value in the second parameter. If the
>   first parameter value is null, it returns the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic in a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE transaction_review
set review1 = coalesce(review1,'Yellow'),
    review2 = (case when review1 is null then review2 else 'Audit' end)
WHERE ACCOUNT = '11111111'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to conditionally choose the column you wish to update without using [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm)

Maybe try using the NVL2 function as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions120.htm

It provides a nice `IF..THEN..ELSE` syntax which may be appropriate for you requirements.

You would have to have two separate `SET` statements if you use the approach described above.