# NVL on many columns - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

create the ORACLE SQL Script statements like below:

```
drop table temp_table;
create table temp_table as (
select
customer_id ,
max (decode (car_type, 'TOYOTA', 'Y', 'N') as Toyota ,
max (decode (car_type, 'BMW', 'Y', 'N') as BMW ,
max (decode (car_type, 'WV', 'Y', 'N') as WV
from purchase
group by customer_id ) ;

alter table main_cust_table
add (
toyota varchar(2) ,
bmw varchar(2) ,
wv varchar(2) ) ;

update main_cust_table c
set ( toyota, bmw, wv ) =
( select toyota, bmw, wv from temp_table d
where d. customer_id = c. customer_id ) ;
commit;
```

some customers still have blanks that need to fill `'N'` on those columns
that same as other customer has detail from `temp_table`

What is the best way to put `nvl`?

I don't feel like creating each column for the individual `update` script statement.

Comment: Why have the temp table - why not update (or merge) the real table directly from the  query? And will you have customers without any purchases? This approach seems wrong overall though - adding a column to the customer table for every make will be painful and maintaining it will add work too - you'll have to update that table when a customer purchases a new car (and potentially when they sell one?). Why not have a view that calculates the Y/N flags on demand?

Comment: Different columns for each car manufacturer? That will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @AlexPoole it is just sample data very different to the actual data at work. I need the correct SQL statement query, which I am seeking guidance from you and other this website

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you don't need `NVL`, but fix `DECODE`. You're missing `'Y'` for the BMW so it says: "if customer drives a BMW, set it to N. Else, set it to NULL".

```
SQL> with purchase (car_type, customer_id) as
  2    (select 'TOYOTA', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'BMW', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'WV', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'BMW', 3 from dual
  6    )
  7  select
  8    customer_id ,
  9    max (decode (car_type, 'TOYOTA', 'Y', 'N')) as Toyota ,
 10    max (decode (car_type, 'BMW'   ,      'N')) as BMW ,  --> missing 'Y'
 11    max (decode (car_type, 'WV'    , 'Y', 'N')) as WV
 12  from purchase
 13  group by customer_id;

CUSTOMER_ID TOYOTA     BMW        WV
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 Y                     N             --> NULL for BMW
          2 N          N          N
          3 N          N          Y

SQL>
```

When fixed:

```
  7  select
  8    customer_id ,
  9    max (decode (car_type, 'TOYOTA', 'Y', 'N')) as Toyota ,
 10    max (decode (car_type, 'BMW'   , 'Y', 'N')) as BMW ,  --> added 'Y'
 11    max (decode (car_type, 'WV'    , 'Y', 'N')) as WV
 12  from purchase
 13  group by customer_id;

CUSTOMER_ID TOYOTA     BMW        WV
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1 Y          N          N          --> no NULL any more, and the whole
          2 N          Y          N          --  BMW column is now fixed
          3 N          Y          Y

SQL>
```

Comment: eerrr... thank you for pinpointing my error typing that missed out 'Y' ,
actually, my boss suggested using "create table" instead of "with" due to the huge database hence to minimise running time to execute the query, since 'create table' has many column blanks that need to fill out after a few subquery

Comment: I used a CTE as a *shortcut* (as you didn't provide any sample data).

Comment: hi again,you mean CTE as WITH statement?

Comment: I thought I already provided an example statement on top because the first one 'create table' has many max(decode) then the next statement in 'alter table' to add new columns based on 'create table' into the main table then the next to update column  'update main_cust_table' to use between those two tables, which some particular customer that is not on the temp_table become blank detail that I would like to use NVL to fill those blank become 'N' after combined result...

Comment: oh...I just got new bulb that might need new statement like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633398/oracle-sql-update-query-only-update-values-if-they-are-null

Comment: I apologize; yes, you provided sample data which I used as a CTE (the WITH factoring clause) instead of creating an actual table. I see you got the answer yourself.

Comment: thank you for helping me here as usual.  I am learning 'technical' SQL to get the resulting output right no idea the term how it works despite google confusing me such as NVL and COALESCE   :)

Answer (score 0):

I got found the solution to add the next new statement as per this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633398/oracle-sql-update-query-only-update-values-if-they-are-null

```
update main_cust_table
set 
toyota = coalesce (toyota, 'N') ,
bmw = coalesce (bmw, 'N') ,
wv = coalesce (wv, 'N') 

where 
toyota is null or
bmw is null or
wv is null;

commit;
```

yes still require typing individual columns per each line

hopefully, I got this right this time.

Thank you to all who read my question and helped me in the right direction!

to add a note:
there is more information about NVL, and COALESCE that skewed my mind at moment
[SQL general functions | NVL, NVL2, DECODE, COALESCE, NULLIF, LNNVL and NANVL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-general-functions-nvl-nvl2-decode-coalesce-nullif-lnnvl-nanvl/)