# Updating Multiple Column with Staging table avoiding Null Values in Staging Table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update multiple column in Table2 table from Table1 table. Staging tables may have null value in it. I just want to update data which has value in the Table1 table - not NULL values.

Please advice

e.g

```
Table 1                             Table 2
ID    col11   col2     col3         ID1      col1       col2       col3
3     test    xxxx     (null)       3        (null)   jjj        ffffff
5     (null)  yyyyy    zzzzzz       5        dddd     (null)     lllllllll
```

Output

```
ID      col1      col2      col3
3        test     xxxx      ffffff
5        dddd     yyyyy     zzzzzz
```

It should not update value in Table 2 will null if value in Table 1 is null.

My approach right now is

```
UPDATE  Table2 
SET ( col1 ,col2,col3)  
      =  (SELECT NVL(col1 ,col11), NVL(col2,col22), NVL(col3,col33)  
          FROM Test1  
          WHERE ID = ID1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Update each column with `COALESCE` of the staging value and the existing target value, supposing the columns are the same or similar types.

This is no different from `NVL` in this simple case, although there are some [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce) worth knowing about, especially portability, and in more complex cases, performance.

While it may seem wasteful to you that each column is technically updated, it is not so.  Once you update a database row, the cost is incurred.  You could make a much more complicated query using dynamic SQL that would do multiple updates, one for each possible column combination, but that solution would be drammatically slower, and obviously, harder to maintain.