# How to treat MAX() of an empty table as 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to select max value from table

```
SELECT MAX(cid) FROM itemconfiguration;
```

However when table `itemconfiguration` is empty the `MAX(cid)` statements is evaluated to `NULL` while i need a number. How to handle this and treat `NULL` as 0 ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just use [Coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) or [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#i91798) to handle NULLs.

The following code will return 0 if `MAX(cid)` is NULL

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(cid), 0)
FROM   itemconfiguration
```

Comment: `COALESCE` is preferable as it is more general (can take more than two arguments and returns the first non-NULL, while `NVL` is its special case for two arguments), it [does short-circuit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/950103/2157640) (does not evaluate arguments after the first non-NULL) and it was standardized in SQL-92 (while `NVL` is proprietary to Oracle).

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT NVL(MAX(cid), 0) FROM itemconfiguration;`

Answer (score 0):

Can replace a number when max return null using **ISNULL** ,

```
ISNULL(MAX(cid),0) FROM itemconfiguration;
```