# I am having trouble using the SQL result set with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

Here is my code:

```
ResultSet res = con.query("USE VSM; SELECT max(EmailTime) FROM Emails;");
if( ! res.next()) { lastEmailTime = new Date(0); } // if table empty set last email time to 1970
else { lastEmailTime = SQLServer.sdf.parse(res.getString(1)); } //SQL is 1-indexed
```

My table is currently empty, and yet the code in the else statement is running. I know this because I'm getting a null pointer exception about it trying to access the res.getString(1). Why is it failing the if condition??

Comment: It looks very strange to have `USE VSM;` in there.  Can you try removing it?

Comment: you can only execute one statement at a time. i don't think USE will work with JDBC. If you need to specify a default schema, you need to prefix your table names:  SELECT max(EmailTime) FROM VSM.Emails

Comment: wow okay. how do I know it will be using the correct database though?

Comment: as i just mentioned, the table prefixing :)  VSM.Emails

Comment: *how do I know it will be using the correct database* you can specify the DB on your connection url

Comment: still getting the error though

Comment: @ScaryWombat there is "database" and "schema". for some databases, the user/schema connection gives them default operations on their own schema, but selecting another schema happens with USE or table prefixing. (I thinking about Oracle here)

Comment: are you actually doing an `executeQuery` ?

Comment: @SlipperySeal OP did ask *how do I know it will be using the correct database though* but good point about db vs schema

Comment: Here is the query method: public ResultSet query(String sql) throws SQLException { return con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql); }

Comment: As the table is empty, an empty field can not be converted into a proper date

Comment: But why is the if statement not triggering?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475059/how-to-treat-max-of-empty-table-as-0-instead-of-null

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(emailTime), now ()) FROM table`

Answer (score -1):

In the jdbc url connection is already defined which database are you using.
You dont need to set the database every single request;

```
    ResultSet res = con.query("SELECT max(EmailTime) FROM Emails;");

if( ! res.next() || res.getString(1) == null) { lastEmailTime = new Date(0); } // if table empty set last email time to 1970
else { lastEmailTime = SQLServer.sdf.parse(res.getString(1)); } //SQL is 1-indexed
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still have the error

Comment: can you run the same query in the database and post the result?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at EmailProcedure.<init>(EmailProcedure.java:26)
 at MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:60)
 at MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:128)

Comment: I asked you to run the query on the database, not to print the stackTrace... open sqldeveloper, phpmyadmin or any other database management interface you have and run the same query you are trying to execute

Comment: Running on SQL Server Management Studio just gives "Command(s) completed successfully." with no actual data returned

Comment: Yeah an empty field can not be converted into a proper date

Comment: The way the data is processed and handled in the ResultSet is defined by the Driver class you are using in your connection... I've never worked with SQLServer drivers so I dont know the implemention details, but maybe as you are using an agregate function it is waiting to always show only one result... in that case one row with null value... you can solve this situation just changing the if

Comment: But why didn't it trigger the if condition?? WHy is the else even running?

Comment: Changing the if how?