# SQL: Output default string for NULL column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am playing with sqlplus command prompt, I want to display a default string, lets say 'ITISNULL' for all NULL columns without updating them.
select * from enrollments where ....

Enrollments is a table which might contain null in its lgrade column. I dont want to update it but just want an output string say, "to be graded" to be printed in its place.

Is there any SQL function I can use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  One option is to use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALSECE(lgrade, 'to be graded')...
```

You can't specify * for all fields, you'll have to specify each column name accordingly.

Comment: another great way to do it.  Never tried testing it, but I wonder if one is faster than the other (most likely not)

Comment: @Limey -- Here is a great post about the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Answer (score 1):

NVL is your answer, you will need to do for every column that could have nulls values

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus you can use `SET NULL`:

```
SQL> SET NULL 'ITISNULL'
SQL> SELECT ...
```

All `NULL` results will display as `ITISNULL`. The only problem is that columns with a width of less than 8 (the length of `ITISNULL`) may wrap - at least they do in my older version of SQL*Plus (9.2).

To return SQL*Plus to its default, issue the following:

```
SQL> SET NULL ''
```

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of ways to show a string when the column is null. As mentioned above, some of the ways :-

1. Use NVL to display 'itisnull' whenever the value of col1 is null.

   ```
   select nvl(col1, 'itisnull') from tableName;
   ```
2. Use CASE to display 'itisnull' whenever the value of col1 is null.

   ```
   select
    case when col1 is null then
    'itisnull'
    else col1
    end colum from tableName;
   ```

Comment: I almost upvoted this but I'm not sure about the if-esle part.  I took a quick look at the docs and I'm not convinced that this is an appropriate place to use that syntax.

Comment: you forgot two of my favorites `NVL2` and `DECODE`