# returning 0 as value for non-existing row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables.

table 1:

```
-------------------------------
| product_id | product number |
-------------------------------
|    1001    |   67E432D      |
|    1002    |   888CDE32     | 
|    1003    |   54D32EC2     |
-------------------------------
```

table 2:

```
--------------------------
| product_id |   desc    |
--------------------------
|  1001      | product 1 |
|  1003      | peoduct 3 |
--------------------------
```

After joining table 1 and table 2 I get the following result.

```
-------------------------------------------
| product_id | product number |   desc    |
-------------------------------------------
|    1001    |   67E432D      | product 1 |
|    1002    |   888CDE32     |           |
|    1003    |   54D32EC2     | product 3 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Now as you can see that the 'desc' column of product 3 is empty now. How may I have a 0 in that column? Something like:

```
-------------------------------------------
| product_id | product number |   desc    |
-------------------------------------------
|    1001    |   67E432D      | product 1 |
|    1002    |   888CDE32     |     0     |
|    1003    |   54D32EC2     | product 3 |
-------------------------------------------
```

There might be some function which can do the job but I guess I am not aware of it..yet.

Comment: Consider changing the column name *desc* into *description* - *desc* is a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use `NVL`

```
SELECT product_id, product_number, NVL( desc, '0' )
  FROM table_1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 USING (product_id)
ORDER BY product_id
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63e5b/3)

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged with *Oracle*, Justin's answer is fine.

If you care about portability, consider using *coalesce*: Based on Justin's answer:

```
SELECT product_id, product_number, coalesce( desc, '0' )
  FROM table_1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 USING (product_id)
ORDER BY product_id
```

As for the difference, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950103/2390083)