# Nested Case/If Else statements in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

I am trying provide an alternative to the calculation I have going in my case statement. Currently it is looking at 'close_date' in order to satisfy the equation. I want it to be able to look at 'close_date' first, but if it is null, then use SYSDATE.

My code is as follows:

```
    SELECT CASE
               WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN
                       ('Complaint')
               THEN
                  (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM work_days1
                    WHERE     work_days1.business_date >
                                 fourthlevel.correspond_date
                          AND work_days1.business_date <=
                                 fourthlevel.close_date)

               WHEN fourthlevel.case_type IN ('Enquiry')
               THEN
                  (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM work_days1
                    WHERE     work_days1.business_date >
                                 fourthlevel.create_date
                          AND work_days1.business_date <=
                                 fourthlevel.close_date)
            END
               AS sla_days
      FROM fourthlevel
```

So do I use a nested if-else statement in my where clauses, or another case statement?

Comment: `coalesce(fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE)`.. more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: nvl(close_date, sysdate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coalesce

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Coalesce checks the first parameter; if null - it uses the second parameter, else it uses the first.

```
COALESCE(fourthlevel.close_date, SYSDATE)
```

This checks `fourthlevel.close_date` then uses `SYSDATE` if the close_date is null.