# SQL Statement for Division - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write a SQL query where I have to select title, year and take the movie cost and divide by the price rent fee for each movie that has a price.

PRICE to MOVIE entity is a 1:M, therefore PRICE_CODE is the FK in entity MOVIE.

This is what I have gotten so far but it keep stating that my operator is invalid.

Can anyone help?

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_year, movie_cost
FROM MOVIE
JOIN PRICE
ON movie.price_code = price.price_code
WHERE (movie_cost)/(price_rentfee);
```

Comment: `WHERE x/y` -- missing an operator after that, (i.e. `=`, `<`, etc.)  Or do you just need to move your `where` criteria to your `select` clause and remove the `where` clause?  A little unclear.

Comment: It's a bit strange that you keep price in a separate table. What's the reason for that?

Comment: The price table is its own because in the table there is a PRICE_RENTFEE and PRICE_DAILYLATEFEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your were close:

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_year, movie_cost/price_rentfee As "Cost to price ratio"
FROM MOVIE
JOIN PRICE
ON movie.price_code = price.price_code
WHERE COALESCE(price_rentfee, 0) > 0;
```

If by any chance you made a typo and `movie_cost` should've been `movie.cost` and `price_rentfee` - `price.rentfee` then it would be like follows:

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_year, movie.cost/price.rentfee As "Cost to price ratio"
FROM MOVIE
JOIN PRICE
ON movie.price_code = price.price_code
WHERE COALESCE(price.rentfee, 0) > 0;
```

Comment: What does COALESCE do? Can i replace that with ROUND because i want it to be 2 decimal places.

Comment: I do not know your schema. If `price` is `nullable` I needed protection. `COALESCE()` is a standard SQL function, that returns its first parameter that is not `null`. When used with just two parameters, it's like Oracle's `NVL()`. See [Oracle Differences between NVL and Coalesce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce) post and its answers.

Comment: Yes, I simply implemented your "*has a price*" requirement. The same helped against division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT movie_title, movie_year, (movie_cost)/(price_rentfee) as 'cost'
FROM MOVIE
JOIN PRICE
ON movie.price_code = price.price_code;
```