# Function alias for Postgres default function

Tags: postgresql

I always use NVL() for assigning a default value when the result is null.

However in PostgreSql there is only COALESCE().

Can I give the COALESCE function an alias so it executes with NVL?

Or can I copy the function declaration somehow?

Comment: What's wrong with using `coalesce()` it's part of the SQL standard and also supported by Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name May sound trite but saving a few letters in the case of applying this function to dozens of columns can matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this wrapper:

```
create or replace function nvl (anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql as $$
    select coalesce($1, $2)
$$;
```

See also [Oracle Differences between NVL and Coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce).

Comment: for me this does not work ATM - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307269/postgres-function-for-nvl

Comment: Well, your function does not work, mine is OK.