# How to count all values from a column, show values in that column and group by a date column?

Tags: sql, database, group-by, distinct

I have a SQL database that has the follow columns: CreatedAt (datetime) and PlatformName (varchar)

```
| CreatedAt  | PlatformName   |
| --------   | -------------- |
| 2021/05/05 | bazinga.ar     |
| 2021/06/06 | rammen.us      |
| 2021/05/05 | iroko.it       |
|  2021/06/06  | sundance.uk    |
```

the relation is one to many (one date to many platformnames), i want to make a query that counts the PlatformNames, shows the distinct PlatformNames and groupby CreatedAt, like this

| CreatedAt | Count(PlatformName) | PlatformName(without duplicates) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/06/02 | 45 | name1, name2, name3 |

this is my query   `SELECT CreatedAt, COUNT(PlatformName) FROM database GROUP BY CreatedAt ORDER BY CreatedAt;`

but i don't know how to show distinct platformnames, is it possible?

Comment: I think you should add a tag specifying the database you're using (the answer may vary)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` for mysql, but it has limitations. 
 or maybe something from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637652/can-we-define-a-group-concat-function-in-postgresql/47638417#47638417

Comment: Tag your database and provide sample data as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: done! it's a simple db

Comment: *simple db* is not a database platform I'm familiar with. You'll find popular tags are MySql, Postgres, MSSqlServer, SqlLite, DB2, Oracle....

Comment: No no!, my doubt, i mean simple because it has only two columns :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem unsure of which database platform you are using, the following works with SQL Server

```
select CreatedAt,
   Count(*) CountOfPlatformName,
   String_Agg(platformName,', ') PlatformNames
from t
group by createdAt
order by createdAt
```

Most database platforms have some sort of string aggregation, if you were using MySql it would be `Group_concat`, so *ymmv*, adjust as appropriate.

Comment: This helped me, the only thing is that i added "distinct" inside the String_add. Thanks a lot