# How to alias a built-in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL v12 introduced `log10()` as an alias for the single-argument invocation of `log()`. However, most hosting providers are still on PostgreSQL v11 or earlier at this time, which do not support `log10()`. In order to make code portable, how can `log10()` be aliased to `log()` in earlier version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function alias for Postgres default function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300728/function-alias-for-postgres-default-function)

Comment: Just use log(x). [Postgres v12 Mathematical Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) contains both log(x) and log10(x) but both return log to base 10.  So its portable for v10 to v12. The only Problem would be downgrading from v12 to v10.

Comment: @Belayer My code has to be portable cross-systems, so I need `log10()`.