# SELECT DISTINCT is omitting NULL values when not desired

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a distinct string in a query, which works unless one of the values is NULL. I've tested removing LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_2, and the query will work just fine. When I do not SELECT DISTINCT, I find that LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_2 values are NULL. How can I gather these values in the SELECT DISTINCT even if NULL?

```
SELECT      DISTINCT(LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 + ', ' + LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_2 + ', ' + LOCATION_CITY + ', ' + LOCATION_WORK_STATE) AS Addresses
FROM        OracleReport
WHERE       (LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%1135 Auto%' OR LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%199 Easy%')
```

Returns:

**Addresses**
NULL

```
SELECT      DISTINCT(LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 + ', ' + LOCATION_CITY + ', ' + LOCATION_WORK_STATE) AS Addresses
FROM        [OperationReport].[dbo].[OracleReport]
WHERE       (LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%1135 Auto%' OR LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%199 Easy%')
```

Returns:

**Addresses**

1135 Auto...

189-199 Easy...

Comment: wrap each value in coalesce(field,'') to change the null to a zero length string.  However if this is Oracle that may not work.  Judging by + use instead of || though coalesce should work fine.

Comment: For Oracle, there's NVL()

Comment: This is a SQL query against a SQL table built from Oracle data. Long story, it's part of a bigger machine that needs to not query Oracle directly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? also: there is no point in using parentheses with distinct. It's **NOT** a function `distinct (a)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a`

Comment: The parentheses are useless nevertheless

Comment: I know it's not a function, but I was applying the distributive property to build one distinct string.

Comment: I see your point, but it's a matter of syntax preference, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind `text,,text,...` (empty string) when a value is NULL...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(coalesce(LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1,'') + ', ' +              
                 coalesce(LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_2,'') + ', ' + 
                 coalesce(LOCATION_CITY,'')  + ', ' + 
                 coalesce(LOCATION_WORK_STATE,'')) AS Addresses
FROM  OracleReport
WHERE (LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%1135 Auto%' 
    OR LOCATION_ADDR_LINE_1 LIKE '%199 Easy%')
```

Coalesce will take the first non-null value and return it.  It requires consistent data types and will early exit once the first non-null value in a series is encountered. (more details [Oracle Differences between NVL and Coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce))

Comment: Never used that before, but it worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: Technically that was Q*Bert