# what is the difference between COALESCE() and NVL()?

Tags: sql, coalesce, nvl

With my practice both function's are giving same output with same functionality..!

select COALESCE(null,1) from dual;
output: 1

select NVL(null,1) from dual;
output: 1

Comment: possible dplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: COALESCE is ANSI SQL standard, NVL is not.