# Lead and case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, lead, case-expression

I have this table:

```
ID    Date
-----------------
1     1/1/2019
1     1/15/2019
```

Expected output:

```
ID   DATE      LEAD_DATE  
-------------------------
1    1/1/2019  1/14/2019
1    1/15/2019  SYSDATE
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.date) = TRUNC(a.date) THEN NULL
        ELSE LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.date) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'second')
    END AS LEAD_DT
 FROM a
```

Results:

```
ID  DATE      LEAD_DATE
-------------------------
 1  1/1/2019    1/14/2019
 1  1/15/2019
```

Can I add the system date when `null` in the case expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NVL` :

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    NVL(CASE 
        WHEN LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY H.ID ORDER BY a.date) = TRUNC(a.date) THEN NULL
        ELSE LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.date) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'second')
    END, SYSDATE) AS LEAD_DT
FROM a
```

Or, better yet :

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    CASE LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.date)
        WHEN TRUNC(a.date) THEN SYSDATE
        WHEN NULL THEN SYSDATE
        ELSE LEAD (a.date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.date) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'second')
    END AS LEAD_DT
 FROM a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`COALESCE`:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950103/3350428).

```
SELECT a.*,
  CASE COALESCE(LEAD("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "Date") - "Date", 0)
    WHEN 0 THEN SYSDATE
    ELSE LEAD("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "Date") - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
  END AS LEAD_DT
FROM a
```