# nvl function not returning expected result

Tags: sql, function, nvl

I know that `nvl` function works only for 'null', not empty string. I just wanted to know if there was a function that helps me replace blank/null values with another one.

I used instead:

```
CASE WHEN expression_1 is null or expression_1 = '' then expression_2 else expression_1
```

expression_1 column has empty cells, not null cells.

Comment: Assuming Oracle, `nvl()` seems to do work on empty strings: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e08b79ba2d9dbd541fa3f934df04e8c1 Maybe your strings aren't really empty but a bunch of spaces?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`NVL()` is a function most typically associated with Oracle.  The equivalent standard SQL function is `COALESCE()`.

By default, Oracle treats `NULL` strings and empty strings (`''`) as the same.  So, `'' IS NULL` evaluates to "true" (and `'' = ''` rather confusingly evaluates to `NULL`, which is false in a `WHERE` clause).

So, you can use `NVL()` or `COALESCE()` on an empty string.  These are the same:

```
NVL(NULL, 'A')
NVL('', 'A')
COALESCE(NULL, 'A')
COALESCE('', 'A')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc6fd55acd4929047bb954fd6f3c9224) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Incase the column contains blank spaces, you can use TRIM() besides NVL() so as you can gracefully remove blank spaces before you apply NVL().

NVL(TRIM('  '),'X')  --> returns X

db<>fiddle -
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08435972cbfb799329e6609349c70a04

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking Coalesce ():

```
coalesce(expression2, expression1)
```

Brings the first non-null value from expression2 else expression 1. If all expressions evaluate to null, then the COALESCE function will return null.

NVL function lets you substitute a value when a null value is encountered:

```
nvl(expression2, expression1)
```

Sql statement would replace expression 2 with with expression 1 if it finds null value in there.

Difference: NVL always evaluates both arguments, while COALESCE usually stops evaluation whenever it finds the first non-NULL

One awesome explanation given by @Quassnoi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce)